# Android - Moving ImageView with Animation on onClick within a android Service

Tags: android

I cannot move ImageView within a Service in Android. This imageView is added using windowManager. 
I want to move it to 0,0 or at left top of the screen.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int[] locations = new int[2];
                imageView.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
                int left = locations[0];
                int top = locations[1];

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "left: "+left+" top: "+top, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(left, 10, top,10);
                animation.setDuration(1000);
                animation.setFillAfter(false);

                imageView.startAnimation(animation);

            }});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, why would you have an image view in a service?

Comment: I am adding them in a service so that they can stay on screen even when Activity is exited.

Comment: But imageView is drawn in a activity, right? Also what is the reason to still display an image after an activity was finished?

Comment: no ImageView is drawn in Service too.

`code`
imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.head);
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
          PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

      params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
      params.x = 0;
      params.y = 0;
      
      windowManager.addView(imageView, params);
`code`

Comment: And ImageView is added In service so that User can use it after Activity is exited. It will remain there as an icon on Screen.